# Python How to print list to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have meet a problem of multiple output.

```
product_list=['Salted Egg Grade A','Salted Egg Grade B','Salted Egg Grade C']
price_list=['30','27','24']
for x in product_list:
  for y in price_list:
    print(x +": "+ y)
```

what I expected is

```
Salted Egg Grade A: 30
Salted Egg Grade B: 27
Salted Egg Grade C: 24
```

What I am getting is

```
Salted Egg Grade A: 30
Salted Egg Grade A: 27
Salted Egg Grade A: 24
Salted Egg Grade B: 30
Salted Egg Grade B: 27
Salted Egg Grade B: 24
Salted Egg Grade C: 30
Salted Egg Grade C: 27
Salted Egg Grade C: 24
```

Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
product_list=['Salted Egg Grade A','Salted Egg Grade B','Salted Egg Grade C']
price_list=['30','27','24']
for x,y in zip(product_list, price_list):
    print(x + ": " + y)
```

Output:

```
Salted Egg Grade A: 30
Salted Egg Grade B: 27
Salted Egg Grade C: 24
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `enumerate()` which basically returns the index as well as the element for each iteration. By using these indices you can loop on the other variable.

```
product_list=['Salted Egg Grade A','Salted Egg Grade B','Salted Egg Grade C']
price_list=['30','27','24']
for index, x in enumerate(product_list):
    print(x +": "+ price_list[index])
```

Comment: I am a beginner in Python. Enumerate is new to me and thank you so much for giving me new vocabulary. It will definitely help me in the future. xD

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
product_list=['Salted Egg Grade A','Salted Egg Grade B','Salted Egg Grade C']
price_list=['30','27','24']
for i in range(len(product_list)):
  print(product_list[i] +": "+price_list[i])
```

Output:

```
Salted Egg Grade A: 30
Salted Egg Grade B: 27
Salted Egg Grade C: 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use for loop here, it's not python way of printing the list. Make use of Zip() function. It takes two equal length list and merges them into a together.

Answer (score 1):

When you printing more than one list better you can make use of ZIP() rather than ENUMERATE() or something else because zip() is the best and fast way to obtain your results.
like

```
for x, y in zip(product_list, price_list):
     print(x + " " + y)
```